# highscore only refreshing on launch sqlite

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have a highscore system implemented using SQLite for a c++ shooter ive made but it only refreshes when I relaunch the game, I think this is because it only re- sorts from largest to smallest on game launch. I don't know why this is, it does seem to record all game scores as it should, but I think it is only ordering them on launch. How could I make it so it re-orders before it prints to screen. Here is the code

in main.cpp

case eHIGH_SCORES:

```
    DrawString( "HIGHSCORES", iScreenWidth * 0.38, iScreenHeight * 0.95);
    DrawString( "PRESS C TO CLOSE", iScreenWidth * 0.32, iScreenHeight * 0.1);

    DatabaseMaker DatabaseMaker("MyDatabase.db");
    DatabaseMaker.CreateDatabase();
    DatabaseMaker.CreateTable("HIGHSCOREST");
    if (scorer<1)
    {
    DatabaseMaker.InsertRecordIntoTable("HIGHSCOREST",scoreArray);
    scorer++;
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        scoreArray[i]=0;
    }
    }
    DatabaseMaker.RetrieveRecordsFromTable("HIGHSCOREST");
    DatabaseMaker.databaseprinter();
```

then in the Database maker class I have

```
    DatabaseMaker::DatabaseMaker(std::string HighScoresT)
    {
        this->HighScores = HighScoresT;
        myDatabase = NULL;  
     }


    int DatabaseMaker::Callback(void* notUsed, int numRows, char **data, char **columnName)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
        {
            std::cout << columnName[i] << ": " << data[i] << std::endl;
            holder.push_back(atoi(data[i]));

         } 

    return 0;
}



void DatabaseMaker::databaseprinter()
{

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        itoa(holder[i], displayHolder, 10);
        DrawString(displayHolder,   780/2,  700-(50*i));
    }

}

void DatabaseMaker::CreateDatabase()
{
    int errorCode = sqlite3_open(HighScores.c_str(), &myDatabase); 

    if(errorCode == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        std::cout << "Database opened successfully." << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "An error has occured." << std::endl;
    }
}

void DatabaseMaker::CreateTable(std::string  HIGHSCOREST)
{

    char* errorMsg = NULL;
    std::string sqlStatement;  

    sqlStatement =  "CREATE TABLE HIGHSCOREST(" \
        "ID  INT," \
        "SCORE    INT);";

    sqlite3_exec(myDatabase, sqlStatement.c_str(), Callback, 0, &errorMsg);

    if(errorMsg != NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Error message: " << errorMsg << std::endl;
    }
}



void DatabaseMaker::InsertRecordIntoTable(std::string HIGHSCOREST,int (&scoreArray)[10] )
{
    char*errorMsg = NULL;
    std::string sqlStatement;
    int x=5;


    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        std::string scorestring;

        scorestring = std::to_string(scoreArray[i]);

        sqlStatement =  "INSERT INTO HIGHSCOREST (ID,SCORE)" \
            "VALUES (1,"+scorestring+");";

        sqlite3_exec(myDatabase, sqlStatement.c_str(), Callback, 0, &errorMsg);

        if(errorMsg != NULL)
        {
            std::cout << "Error message: " << errorMsg << std::endl;
        }
    }

}

void DatabaseMaker::RetrieveRecordsFromTable(std::string HIGHSCOREST)
{

    char* errorMsg = NULL;
    std::string sqlStatement;

    sqlStatement =  "SELECT SCORE from HIGHSCOREST order by SCORE desc;";

    sqlite3_exec(myDatabase, sqlStatement.c_str(), Callback, 0, &errorMsg);

    if(errorMsg != NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Error message: " << errorMsg << std::endl;
    }

    sqlite3_close(myDatabase); 


}


DatabaseMaker::~DatabaseMaker()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe try to move `sqlite3_close` statement off the `RetrieveRecordsFromTable` member function, maybe to destructor or seperate function?

Since you close connection to database after calling it for first time (and this might be a reason the problem is fixed by rerunning your application).

Also, consider changing this `DatabaseMaker DatabaseMaker("MyDatabase.db");` into this: `DatabaseMaker databaseMaker("MyDatabase.db");`, otherwise you might have problem defining another `DatabaseMaker` in same scope.

Comment: I tried moving the SQLite close function, and also removing it completely, still doesn't work... did help with something else but not the original problem :( also I know the databasemaker naming is bad but this is all the thing has to do so It should be fine ?

Comment: also just did some testing... If i clear the database, it accepts the first insert fine, any further insert only is seen after restart, this further suggests that it is simply only applying the sort on restart, or some similar related problem. if there is anything else i could show that might help anyone just ask

Comment: Well, while displaying results you are printing 10 first elements of vector, always. But when collecting new elements from database you indeed add them to vector sorted, but **at the end**. Try putting `holder.clear()` before loop in `Callback` member function.